# Algebraic Transformation query...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, transformation

I'm boning up on Algebra, and I'm looking into Algebraic Transformation.
I understand the basic concept - but I'm confused by two self assessment questions.

The two questions, from what I can see, are *almost* similar but have quite different ways of arriving at the end result.

Now, what I'm confused about is why the two different approaches.

**First example** is thus (make N the subject):

$$R = \frac{2N}{C-P}$$

Stage 1:
$$R(C-P) = 2N$$

Stage 2:

$$R \frac{C-P}{2}=N$$

**Second Example**, make L the subject

$$D = \frac{CL^2}{2+R}$$

Stage 1:

$$D(2+R) = CL^2$$

Stage 2:

$$\frac{D}{C}(2 + R) = L2$$

I'm confused as to why in the first example (C - P) is divided by the coefficient 2, whereas in Example 2 D is divided by C.

Is there a 'reason' or 'rule' why the two different approaches, or does it come down to understanding the formula and working it out?

Sorry for such a basic question - still learning.

Many thanks for any and all replies.

Comment: Sorry, just figuring out how to use the MathJax formatting; please hold the line...

Comment: Ok, sorted the formatting out, and having done now what I should have done before posting, which is insert some figures and check the results - is that using either method above yields the same result. I do find Maths fascinating :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the first example again:
$$R = \frac{2N}{C-P}$$
You want to get $N$ on its own. So you first get rid of the $C-P$ downstairs. This is achieved by multiplying both sides of the equation by $C-P$, giving $R(C-P) = 2N$. Now, to get $N$ on its own we divide both sides of the equation by 2. Giving the answer $N = \frac{R(C-P)}{2}$.

Let's look at the second example:
$$D = \frac{CL^2}{2+R}$$
You want to get $L$ on its own. So you first get rid of the $2+R$ downstairs. This is achieved by multiplying both sides of the equation by $2+R$, giving $D(2+R) = CL^2$. Now, to get $L^2$ on its own we divide both sides of the equation by C. Giving the answer $L^2 = \frac{D(2+R)}{C}$. Finally, we need to get rid of the power of two, so we square-root both sides:
$$L = \pm\sqrt{\frac{D(2+R)}{C}}.$$
(We need the $\pm$ because if $x^2 = 4$ then $x = -2$ works since $(-2)^2=4$ and $x=+2$ also works since $(+2)^2=4.$ Hence $x^2 = 4$ means $x=-2$ or $x=+2$, i.e. $x=\pm 2$.

Comment: Sorry added to above: I understand what you are saying about the example 2, but the answer they give in my examples does not match what you wrote. They state that D/C * (2+R) = L2 ; which is the bit that throws me.

Comment: @JustADoofus That's a typo on their part. If in the future you see a change that doesn't seem to follow without some missing info, even if it's reasonable, either prove or disprove it. If it's true, you learn something good, if it's false, it saves you from filling your head with nonsense.

Comment: @LokiClock Thanks - I see your point!